# $injector:modulerr Module Error after publishing application on IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, obfuscation, minifiedjs

HI I have issue that appears after publishing AngularJS application on IIS server
I believe this has something to do with javascript obfuscation and minification but I don't know how to fix it...

This is how my app.js look like

```
angular.module('app', ['LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar', 'smart-table', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'LocalStorageModule', 'app.filters', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.controllers'])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            layout: 'basic',
            templateUrl: 'views/index',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'

        })
        .state('putninalozi', {
            url: '/putninalozi',
            layout: 'basic',
            templateUrl: 'views/PutniNalozi',
            controller: 'PutniNaloziCtrl'
        })
        .state('profil', {
            url: '/profil',
            layout: 'basic',
            templateUrl: 'views/profil',
            controller: 'ProfilCtrl'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            layout: 'basic',
            templateUrl: 'views/login',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .state('signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            layout: 'basic',
            templateUrl: 'views/signup',
            controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
        })
        .state('otherwise', {
            url: '*path',
            templateUrl: 'views/404',
            controller: 'Error404Ctrl'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}])

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
})

.run(['authService', '$templateCache', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function (authService, $templateCache, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

    authService.fillAuthData();
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

}]);
```

And for example one of my controllers looks like this

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', '$window', 'authService', function ($scope, $location, $timeout, $window, authService) {

     $scope.loginData = {
         userName: "",
         password: ""
     };

     $scope.message = "";

     $scope.login = function () {

         authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {

             $location.path('/putninalozi');

         },
          function (err) {
              $scope.message = err.error_description;
          });
     };

 }])
```

Any idea how to fix this issue ? Thank you for all opinions

my BundleCOnfig.cs looks like this

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css/app").Include("~/content/app.css")
                                                        .Include("~/content/custom.css")
                                                        .Include("~/content/loading-bar.css"));


      //  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/jquery").Include("~/scripts/vendor/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/app").Include(
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular.min.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/smart-table.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular-strap.min.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular-strap.tpl.min.js",                    
              "~/scripts/app.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular-ui-router.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/loading-bar.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular-animate.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular-route.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular-sanitize.min.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/angular-local-storage.min.js",
              "~/scripts/vendor/bootstrap.js",
              "~/scripts/controllers.js",
              "~/scripts/filters.js",
              "~/scripts/services.js",
              "~/scripts/directives.js"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with minification . Have you set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` ?

Comment: No i don't have that peace of code

Comment: Do you have a `BundleConfig.cs` with all the javascript files added to to the bundle?

Comment: yes, i have BundleConfig.cs

Comment: I just add BundleConfig.cs in question

Comment: Could you try to add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in your `RegisterBundles` method?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I think i found the solution. It's look like on local server (from Visual Studio) default option BundleTable.EnableOptimizations is false. But when you publish on IIS on serwer is true. Try to add **BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false** in **BundleConfig.cs**

Answer (score 0):

To enable minification, ensure the following:

- Config.asax, register the BundlesConfig

  ```
  protected void Application_Start()
  {
      BundlesConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  }
  ```
- BundleConfig.cs, include the scripts and enable optimizations

  ```
  public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
  {
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
      "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
  }
  ```
- main.html, register the scripts

  ```
  @section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  }
  ```
- In addition the minification process changes $scope and $q into random variables. Since this does nto tell angular what to inject, the solution is to declare your dependencies wrapped in `[]`:

  ```
  angular.module("MyApp")
    .controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$q", function($scope, $q) {
    // your code
  }])
  ```

This is just the steps you need to enable minification. [This](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) is an article on how to actual to this

Answer (score 0):

in you ScriptBundle remove angular.min, angular-local-storage.min and add the unminified versions of them